# How do I plot velocity in sherical coordinates using python

Tags: python-3.x

[Picture the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Ucr.png)

This is an engineering dynamics problem, were we are required to plot velocity and acceleration in python using spherical coordinates.

Comment: Please provide the code you have produced so far. Question: Is this something you have elected to do on your own or for a course? If for a course, what course?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.